# Selenium Multiple Elements in a Screenshot

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question about taking multiple screenshots on a web page using the Selenium Module in Python. I have a program that takes a screenshot of 2 elements (next to each other), in separate files. However, I want them to be together in one image. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def get_concat_h_cut(im1, im2):
    dst = Image.new('RGB', (im1.width + im2.width,
                            min(im1.height, im2.height)))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (im1.width, 0))
    return dst


def get_concat_v_cut(im1, im2):
    dst = Image.new(
        'RGB', (min(im1.width, im2.width), im1.height + im2.height))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
    return dst

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
a=io.BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(
))

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
b = io.BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(
))

a= Image.open(a)
b = Image.open(b)

get_concat_h_cut(a, b).save('d:/pillow_concat_h_cut.jpg')
get_concat_v_cut(a, b).save(
    'd:/pillow_concat_v_cut.jpg')
```

you can use pillow module in python to combine images together